# How to stop vector movement

Tags: java

I made this program where the player moved from a starting point to an end point (I'll be referencing "RedDot with end point) by a push of a button using vectors. The player moves to the end point perfectly fine, but instead of stopping at the point it moves past it. As you can see in my update function the vector movement.

```
 public void update(float dt) {

    if (InputManager.isTriggered(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {
        enter += 1;
    }
    if (InputManager.isTriggered(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)) {
        enter -= 1;
    }

    if (enter == 1) {

        Vec2 direction = new Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
        direction.setX(-RedDot.getPositionX() - 100);
        direction.setY(RedDot.getPositionY() - 100);
        direction.normalize();
        CloudPlayer.setVelocity(Vec2.scale(direction, speed));
    }

}
```

I tried things like changing the speed variable after a certain amount of time but it doesn't work

Comment: Should I have one? I could set it up to check where the position of the player is but my only problem is trying to stop it from moving

Comment: Can you post a MCVE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what is CloudPlayer? what is dt? what is the current position?